# How can I write a function that does nothing for a given length of time?

Tags: python

Here's what I tried (Python):

```
import time

def wait(seconds):
    start_time = time.time()
    while start_time + seconds <= time.time():
        pass
```

But this just quits instantly.

Comment: The best answer has already been given, but your code also works, if you replace `<=` with `>=`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code will efficiently sleep for a specified amount of time

```
import time
time.sleep(1) # delays for 1 second
```